# The equivalence of two definitions for accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Usually, we define accumulation point as:

1) A point x is called accumulation point of a set X if for every ε>0, the ε-neighborhood of x contains an element of X \ {x}.

But today I also saw another one:

2) A point x is called accumulation point of a set X if for every ε>0, the ε-neighborhood of x contains infinitely many elements of X.

I think they are equivalent, but how can I prove it? Could you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your question implies that the underlying topological space is a metric space. These two definitions are indeed equivalent under this assumption. It's worth noting, however, that these two definitions correspond to different concepts in the more general setting of topological spaces.

Let's show that the definitions are equivalent for metric spaces. it's easy to see that (2) implies (1). Now assume (1) holds. Let $p_1 \in B_\epsilon(x) - \{x\}$. Let $\epsilon_2 = d(x, p_1)$. Obtain $p_2 \in B_{\epsilon_2}(x) - \{x\}$. Repeat this process to get an infinite sequence of distinct elements $\{p_i\} \subset B_\epsilon(x) - \{x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$(2)\implies(1)$

If $U$ is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ and contains infinitely many points of $X$ then evidently $U-\{x\}\neq\varnothing$.

$\neg(2)\implies\neg(1)$

Let it be that some $\epsilon>0$ exists such that $X\cap B(x,\epsilon)$ is finite.

Then consequently: $$\epsilon':=\min\{d(x,y)\mid y\in (X-\{x\})\cap B(x,\epsilon)\}>0$$
so that: $$(X-\{x\})\cap B(x,\epsilon')=\varnothing$$

Comment: this would work in any space in which points are closed (i.e. any T$_1$ space). For $\neg(2)\implies\neg(1)$ take any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $X\cap U$ is finite, say $X\cap U=\{y_1,...,y_n\}$. Then $V=U\setminus(\{y_1,...,y_n\}\setminus\{x\})$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ meeting no other elements of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

1 is usually called a limit point.
In a Hausdorff space, which metric spaces are, they are equivalent.
Clearly 2 implies 1.
Now assume x is an limit point of X.
Let U be an open ball about.
Thus exists a in X, different than a.
Find an r-ball about x that excludes a.
Whence exists b in X different than a and different than x.
Proceed thusly to find a sequence of distinct points, a, b, c,... in ever smaller balls.
Whereupon x is an accumulation point of X (definition 2).

Comment: if your proof is to work in any Hausdorff space, you mean "open set" or "open neighborhood", rather that "open ball" or $r$-ball". The sentence "Thus exists $a$ in $X$, different than $a$" is not what you meant. You want $a$ in $U\cap X$ (and further down $b$ in $U\cap X$). Also, $a$ different from $a$ should be $a$ different from $x$. The assumption that the space is T$_1$ would be sufficient, since then $U$, $U\setminus\{a\}$, $U\setminus\{a,b\}$, $U\setminus\{a,b,c\}$, etc, would all be open sets. Then $\{a,b,c,...\}$ would be an infinite set of points in $U\cap X$ distinct from $x$.